# Painfully slow smtp mail on my Digital Ocean Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, digital-ocean

I have a registration script that sends an email to a user upon successful registration. It takes 30 minutes to send this email on my Digital Ocean droplet, but it works perfectly from my localhost running MAMP.

I need to know what to check to diagnose this problem. What needs to be configured on my server to get this to work properly?

My mail script looks like this.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl" ;
$mail->From        = "noreply@domain.com";
$mail->Timeout    = 60;
$mail->Host       = "smtp.zoho.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->Username   = "noreply@domain.com";
$mail->Password   = 'myPassword';
```

Comment: Have you tried using mailgun? I've been using it for a while. You can try it out to figure out whether it's a server issue or service issue.